# How to exceed the 30mins time on Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am pulling file list on spreadsheet and some folders will take 1 hour to get all the data. How can I exceed my time limit to get all the data? Currently limit is 30mins.

Here is my code:

```
function myFunction() {
  
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.clear();
    sheet.appendRow(["Market","Folder","Employee","FileName", "Date Last Updated", "Size", "URL", "ID", "Description", "Type"]);
    

    var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Root Folder 1');
    var foldersnext = folders.next();
    var subfolders = foldersnext.getFolders();
  

    while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    var subfolderdata = [];
    var mysubfolders = subfolders.next();
    var files = mysubfolders.searchFolders("title contains 'Cap'");

    var getfilez = files.next();

    var mysubfiles = getfilez.getFiles();
   
    while (mysubfiles.hasNext()) {
      var smyfile = mysubfiles.next();
      var sfname =  smyfile.getName();
      var sfdate =  smyfile.getLastUpdated(); 
      var sfsize =  smyfile.getSize();
      var sfurl =  smyfile.getUrl();
      var sfid =  smyfile.getId();
      var sfdesc =  smyfile.getDescription();
      var sftype =  smyfile.getMimeType();

      subfolderdata = [ 
        (foldersnext),
        (getfilez),(mysubfolders),
        sfname,
        sfdate,
        sfsize,
        sfurl,
        sfid,
        sfdesc,
        sftype
      ];
     
      sheet.appendRow(subfolderdata); }}}
```

Comment: By using `appendRow()` you are hitting the sheet for each row. That is slow and inefficient. See [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices). Instead, create an array of `subfolderdata` and post it to the sheet once after collecting all the data. See if that helps the script finish in less than 30min.

Comment: Can you help me on making this code for the array? I am new to this language and still learning. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to put everything in one place:

By using `appendRow()` you are hitting the sheet for each row. That is slow and inefficient. See [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices).

Instead, create an array of `subfolderdata` and post it to the sheet once after collecting all the data. See if that helps the script finish in less than 30min.

To achieve this, initialise an array right at the begining:

```
var postDataArray = [];
```

Then, for the header row of the sheet, instead of:

```
sheet.appendRow(["Market","Folder","Employee","FileName", "Date Last Updated", "Size", "URL", "ID", "Description", "Type"]);
```

add the header row to the array:

```
postDataArray.push(["Market","Folder","Employee","FileName", "Date Last Updated", "Size", "URL", "ID", "Description", "Type"]);
```

Then inside the `while` loop, instead of

```
sheet.appendRow(subfolderdata);
```

use

```
postDataArray.push(subfolderdata);
```

And then after the `while` loop, use the following to post the data to the sheet:

```
sheet.getRange(1, 1, postDataArray.length, postDataArray[0].length).setValues(postDataArray);
```

`postDataArray.length` is the number of rows.

`postDataArray[0].length` is the number of columns.

---

PS: Best to test the code for a few hundred rows instead of waiting for 30 minutes to figure out it is broken.

Add a counter that breaks the `while` loop once it hits say 500.